# What video player will speed up, slow down, & play backwards on the fly?

Tags: video

I'd like to set up some physical buttons and dials to control the playback of a long video. I'd like to have a video player which allows me to switch to an arbitrary playback speed at any time while I'm watching the video, even if it's a negative value (backwards).

VLC lets you increase and decrease the playback speed of a video, but doesn't support backwards playback. Nor does it allow you to jump to a specific playback speed, except for at startup with the `--rate` option (you must step though the different playback speeds).

Is there such a video player? (And does it run on Linux? -- this would be ideal, but isn't essential.)

Comment: See also here http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6907/video-player-with-backward-frame-by-frame-stepping-for-linux

Answer (score 1):

**KMPlayer** can play backwards, but if you are looking for a more portable and user friendly option, I suggest **VLC**, that has so many distros for Linux, Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the QuickTime player on the Mac (and Windows?) can play a video backwards:

> QuickTime Player offers a number of arrow key
>   functions that go beyond simple scrubbing. For example, holding the
>   Option key lets you jump to the start or end of your video. What's
>   really cool is when you press Command-Left-Arrow. Your video starts
>   playing in reverse. Repeat that key sequence to change the rate at
>   which your movie plays backwards. (The same trick holds for normal
>   playback. Command-Right-Arrow goes from normal play to accelerated
>   options.

http://www.engadget.com/2013/10/17/5-quicktime-player-secrets/