# What video player in Linux allows to play backwards

Tags: linux, video, media-player

What video player in Linux allows to play backwards?

Following answer is incorrect: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/19236/18701 - KMplayer or VLC do not allow this.

Comment: Play backward as in play in reverse can be done by __avidemux__ in linux. [Reverse Movie FX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile.bizo.reverse&hl=en) in android.

Comment: It is an editor - need player. Do not see such option in it either, also hanging every time on play.

Comment: Do you need the audio to reverse at the same time as the video?

Comment: No, video is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video editors can do this. [OpenShot](http://openshot.org/) has a `Seek Backward` button that can run at -1X, -2X, -4X, -8X, etc. [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) has the same feature, but the button is called `Rewind`. Neither of them play sound backward, though.

(Video players like VLC or Kmplayer are designed to work in situations like live streaming. To be able to run backward, they would have to either write everything to disk or store it all in memory, neither of which are desirable for streaming.)